# How to evenly distribute menu items with CSS when width and quantity is not known?

Tags: css, menu, tabs, distributed

I've read a lot on evenly distributing elements using css but every solution i've found requires you to know and define the width and/or the number of elements being distributed.

I have a container that is of a fixed width - within here could be any number of li elements of an automatic width which need to be distributed evenly across the parent element from left to right.

Here is my markup - except there could be any number of tabs with any length text in them.

```
<ul class="tabs">
     <li class="tab active" id="tab-1"><span class="tab-title">Tab 1</span></li>
     <li class="tab " id="tab-2"><span class="tab-title">Tab 2</span></li>
     <li class="tab " id="tab-3"><span class="tab-title">Tab 3</span></li>
     <li class="tab " id="tab-4"><span class="tab-title">Tab 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

So Even Distribution with css when the number of elements and width is dynamic - can it be done?

Seems like such an obvious thing to want to do - Damn CSS!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this, you can use the CSS `display:table-cell` property. Write this:

```
.tabs {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.tabs li {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px7Uf/).

Comment: Thanks!!  Doesn't work in IE 7 but who cares, I'm fed up of fixing things for out of date IE versions.

Comment: Brilliant. Also just a note for anyone finding this to remove any floats you have on `<li>` elements.

Comment: I'd like to revisit this now does anyone have different way to achieve the same thing without using display:table-cell?  It doesn't play nice with drop-down menus and css transitions.

Comment: @Ralphonz: added an answer, creating true equally sized columns. The solution above is dependent on content length equality to work.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that keeps even widths when contents overflow the allocated cell width, using flexbox:

```css
ul.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.tabs>li.tab {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  /* just adding visibility to the tabs */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12); 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
     <li class="tab active" id="tab-1"><span class="tab-title">Tab 1</span></li>
     <li class="tab " id="tab-2"><span class="tab-title">Tab 2</span></li>
     <li class="tab " id="tab-3"><span class="tab-title">Tab 3. This is a very long tab and should overflow...</span></li>
     <li class="tab " id="tab-4"><span class="tab-title">Tab 4</span></li>
</ul>
```