# Add/remove panel horizontally and dynamically adjust class boostrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, coffeescript

Hi I've probably just missed something really simple. But I have several rows with panels in it and I want to adjust the col-md- class based on the number of panels. I want this to happen on load and on some click events aswell. I use coffescript and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can change the Bootstrap classes in your scripts as you suggest. Suppose that your html looks as follows:

```
<div class="my-row row">
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
</div>
<div class="my-row row">
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 my-col"> ... </div>
</div>
...
```

In this case, the code like this would do the job (see a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t9qbkcnb/)):

```
$('...').on 'click', ->
  $('.my-row').each (i, row) ->
    $panels = $(row).find('.my-col')
    numPanels = $panels.length
    desiredPanelWidth = Math.floor 12 / numPanels # or whatever function you want
    $panels.each (j, col) ->
      col.className = col.className.replace /\bcol-md-\d+\b/, "col-md-#{desiredPanelWidth}"
```

However, if what you want is to spread the panels evenly within each row, it would be better to use CSS tools like those recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551369/how-to-evenly-distribute-menu-items-with-css-when-width-and-quantity-is-not-know).